# uwsim problem while installation in indigo

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, uwsim, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i tried the steps for installation on my ros-indigo as stated in this page
http://www.irs.uji.es/uwsim/wiki/index.php?title=Installing_UWSim
but ,
when i run rosrun uwsim uwsim this command . i am getting an error

```
yuvaram@yuvaram-Lenovo-G40-45:~$ rosrun uwsim uwsim
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named uwsim below /opt/ros/indigo/share/uwsim
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /opt/ros/indigo/share/uwsim
```

**steps i follower while installing**

1. sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-uwsim
2. roscore
3. rosrun uwsim uwsim

it will be a great help if someone can figure out what my problem is and help me with this
thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225779/uwsim-problem-while-installation-in-indigo/) by [yuvaram](https://answers.ros.org/users/25672/yuvaram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm not sure what the problem is. But I would say is not an issue totally related with UWSim and maybe something is wrong with ros installation. Have you checked the folders actually exist? ( /opt/ros/indigo/share/uwsim ). Have you tried other installed ROS packages?, for instance you can try [osg interactive markers](http://wiki.ros.org/osg_interactive_markers) which is installed with uwsim.

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2016-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0